# Missing column in Shopping Cart Table in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, shopping-cart

Here is my snapshot:

[image]

The row of "Angel Light Running Short" does not having column stock.

And then I tried to empty my `app/code/Company/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml`

and then it become like this:

[image]

My question is why "Angel Light Running Short" does not uses default.phtm ?

How to add a new column to "Angel Light Running Short" ?

Comment: stop using Magento dude, its ugly and painful, its created to make Web development painful and costly, use Laravel instead!

Comment: I think what you just said is make sense

Comment: this is not a answer of question

Comment: yeah that's not an answer, do you have any answer for this case @RutveeSojitra ?