# Magento 2 view product give different result for different category

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout

For learning purpose I just added following css in my Module:

[image]

```
.newcolor
{
   background: #ffff00 !important;
   box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px 1px rgba(66, 103, 178, 0.51);
   font-size: 23px !important;
   font-weight: bold !important;
   border-radius: 10px;
   height: 60px;
   font-family: cursive !important;
}
```

**Class newcolor implementation in addtocart.phtml**

[image]

```
<div class="actions">
        <button type="submit"
                title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                class="action primary tocart newcolor"
                id="product-addtocart-button">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
        </button>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
    </div>
```

**Here is my Layout**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
        <css src="Senheng_Mycart::css/colorcart.css"/>
   </head>

   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
           <action method="setTemplate">
               <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Senheng_Mycart::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
           </action>
       </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

**Result:**

Its working well for this product (button become yellow).

[image]

**But does not work for "short pant" product.**

[image]

My Question is why class 'newcolor' does not shown in the product with category "short pant" ?

Comment: I would be way easier to read and answer if instead of screenshots of code you added the actual code.

Comment: okay wait a moment

Comment: @Marius its updated

Comment: @YusufIbrahim please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the reason why you have not see the diffrent product with your custom css:

check in

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml

```
                    <?php if (!$block->hasOptions()):?>
                                <?= $block->getChildHtml('product_info_form_content') ?>
                            <?php else:?>
                                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container1'):?>
                                    <?= $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
                                <?php endif;?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->hasOptions() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container2'):?>
                                <?= $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
                            <?php endif;?>
                            <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_bottom') ?>
```

Now go to **catalog_product_view.xml**

```
                            <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                                                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                                                </container>
                                                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
                                                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
                                                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml">
                                                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.default" as="default" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                                                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" name="product.info.options.text" as="text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                                                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" name="product.info.options.file" as="file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                                                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" name="product.info.options.select" as="select" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                                                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" name="product.info.options.date" as="date" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
                                                        </block>
                                                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
                                                    </block>
```

check if product has option first container will load and if product hasn't option another block will call where **addtocart.phtml** call differently

your **catalog_product_view.xml** should be

```
               <body>
                <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="Senheng_Mycart::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                  </referenceContainer>
                   <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
                       <action method="setTemplate">
                           <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Senheng_Mycart::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
                       </action>
                   </referenceBlock>
               </body>
            </page>
```

Comment: hi, I will check it tomorrow mate, thank you

Comment: I am sorry I still don't understand how to fix it based on your information

Comment: You have to change product.info.form.content container 's template too @YusufIbrahim

Comment: please check i have updated it in my answer just replace your catalog_product_view.xml with mine @YusufIbrahim

Comment: I got following error "Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'as': The attribute 'as' is not allowed."

Comment: and then I removed "as" attribute from referenceContainer and everything still remain the same

Comment: by the way could you please help me with another question at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276368/missing-column-in-shopping-cart-table-in-magento-2 ? I think its same issue